# ROS logger disables Python logger

Tags: python, logging, ros, python-logging, rospy

I am having issues with the Python logger and the rospy logger. In the begining, the Python logger stopped logging as soon as a ROS node was initialized. I tried to solve the problem by adding a stream handler to the logger. Now it only logs if a ROS node is initialized.

I read about rospy and python logging conflicts in the [ROS git](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1384) but there seems to be no nice solution to use the python logger exclusively and independent from the ROS logger for my code.

some module initializing the logger:

```
    path = "/some_directory/"
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger('logger_name')

    # logging file handler for basic log infos
    file_handler_info = logging.FileHandler('{}log.log'.format(path))
    file_handler_info.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler_info.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler_info)

    # logging file handler for critical warnings
    file_handler_critical = logging.FileHandler('{}critical.log'.format(path))
    file_handler_critical.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler_critical.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler_critical)

    # logging stream handler for console output
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

some other module starting the ROS node

```
logger.info("This message will not be displayed")
rospy.init_node('node_name', anonymous=True)
logger.info("This message will be displayed")
```

Answer (score 1):

rospy provides [overriding the default logging configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging#Advanced:_Override_Logging_Configuration):

> By default, rospy and other ROS python libraries use $ROS_ROOT/../../etc/ros/python_logging.conf. This file is the standard fileConfig format used by the Python logging module (see https://docs.python.org/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format).
>
> You can override the location of this configuration file by setting the ROS_PYTHON_LOG_CONFIG_FILE environment variable.

Customize or create your own version of the `python_logging.conf` which is placed at `/opt/ros/YOUR_ROS_DISTRO/etc/ros/` by default.

Maybe it is already enough to add the `streamHandler` to the root logger:

```
[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler,streamHandler
```